# sorting sql data with subquery alias by using fluent-nhibernate-queryover

Tags: c#, sorting, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, subquery

how can I sort sql data with subquery alias in nhiberante queryover ? You can see the example below.

```
select Name, 
       (select count(Id) from Orders ...) as 'OrderCount'
from Customer
order by OrderCount desc
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a draft of a `QueryOver`. It consists of a subquery, representing the count of Orders. The root query over the Customer, then uses this to create a SELECT projection and ORDER BY projection.

```
Customer customer = null;
Orders orders = null;

// the subselect of a count
var subQuery = QueryOver.Of<Orders>(() => orders)
    .Where(() => orders.Customer.ID == customer.ID)
    .Select(Projections.RowCount());

// the alias of the Customer to be injected into subquery
var query = session.QueryOver<Customer>(() => customer);

query.SelectList(l => l
    .Select(p => p.Name).WithAlias(() => customer.Name)
    // see the customer.Count property
    .Select(Projections.SubQuery(subQuery)).WithAlias(() => customer.Count)
    );

// Order by the count (desc)
var list = query
    .OrderBy(Projections.SubQuery(subQuery))
        .Desc
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<Customer>())
    .List<Customer>()
    ;
```

In this example we expect that Customer has some C# property `Count`, which is populated during transformation of this query. If not, we can create some CustomerDTO...

Comment: Hi, my sorting column is dynamic and passed into method as string. I need something like  .OrderBy("Count").

Comment: This is not what you need for sure ;) Do you know why? Because the *alias* (e.g. "Count") is not evaluated in the ORDER BY. You simply have to pass the same expression passed to the SELECT. The answer I gave you is in fact doing both. Based on some passed parameters from upper layers... you will create the detached query. Then you will use it for SELECT and ORDER BY... 2 wins in one round through ;)